# Можно ли в Visual Studio определить в какой строчке кода изменилось значение переменной?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Можно ли в Visual Studio определить в какой строчке кода изменилось значение переменной?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/160074/2752075

Comment: О, святой Черный кот, спасибо вам!